# Define default value for Grafana dashboard variable

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-dashboard

I have defined a variable in a Grafana dashboard through Grafana dashboard settings
Variable is of "Custom" type.
I want this variable having a default value when dashboard is opened.

How can I set a default value ?

Answer (score 18):

1. Choose your default value in dashboard and then save dashboard.
2. **Tick "Save current variable values as dashboard default".**
3. Default value is now set to the value you chose.

Comment: Which grafana version is this?

Comment: These steps do not work for sharing dashboards externally. Any idea how we can use a default variable value for sharing dashboards externally?

Comment: This didn't work with grafana 8.1.5.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid ClickOps by interacting with Grafana UI to persist config changes, then you can modify Grafana's dashboard JSON model - this will allow you to share your dashboard.

Let's say that you have defined your custom variable (like on the image below), and you would like to set `1[m]` as a default value.

[image]

Then what you should do next, is to find this variable definition in Grafana's dashboard JSON model (look at `templating.list` location) and set `"selected"` to `true` in `"options"` and add/modify `"current"` section. Your config should resemble below settings.

```json
...
"current": {
  "selected": true,
  "text": "1m",
  "value": "1m"
},
"options": [
  {
    "selected": true,
    "text": "1m",
    "value": "1m"
  },
  {
    "selected": false,
    "text": "3m",
    "value": "3m"
  },
  ...
],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in Grafana v9.5.8:

1. Open the Dashboard Settings
2. Navigate to "Variables"
3. Open the desired Variable
4. Check -> "Include All option" (you'll finde them at the Bottom)
5. Under "Custom all value" Field, add your Default Value
6. Save Dashboard